# "In my younger years, early days, early years, and earlier years"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I just wanted to express the period from when I was born to my recent days until I realized something.

I initially put "in my earlier years." Then I wasn't sure if the meaning of the phrase that I made communicate precisely as I intended.

So I looked up and got few more similar expressions such as, "my early years", "In my early life", "In my younger and vulnerable years", "in my younger age", etc.

Yet, I sensed all of them insinuate more like a childhood, not necessarily includes, for instance, my few weeks ago until I realized something.

Is there any proper expression or phrase for a such case?

Comment: I think you might have to rephrase this to something like "Until recently/until a few years ago" or "I always used to [think/believe] but recently I ....". It might depend on how old you are now. If you are 87 you would say "All my life I have [believed ]....". But if you are 21 you could say "As I grew up I always [thought]...."

Comment: Before the scales fell from my eyes: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+scales+fall+from+eyes

Comment: I'm with @Mynamite that it's relative. If you're very old, _early years_ or _younger days_ could easily include everything up to middle age. But if you're just a young adult, they would mean childhood.

Comment: I think the phrase, "for my whole life until recently," conveys what you're after. A slight variation would be, "for most of my life until recently," which I suppose is technically more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Summary of the comments:

> "Until recently/until a few years ago" or "I always used to [think/believe] but recently I ....". It might depend on how old you are now. If you are 87 you would say "All my life I have [believed ]....". But if you are 21 you could say "As I grew up I always [thought]..."
> -- [Mynamite Aug 20](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192456/in-my-younger-years-early-days-early-years-and-earlier-years#comment401561_192456)
>
> "for my whole life until recently," conveys what you're after. A slight variation would be, "for most of my life until recently," which I suppose is technically more accurate.
> -- [G Tony Jacobs Aug 23](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192456/in-my-younger-years-early-days-early-years-and-earlier-years#comment403139_192456)